# how the computer convert a number of signed int to unsigned int

Tags: c

I am wondering why this code will output -5 , since they are of different types, and -5 is a very large in unsigned considering 2's complement

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        unsigned int x = -5; //
        printf("%d", x);

    }
```

I am very confused, how a signed int be converted into unsigned? thanks!

Comment: This code actually does the exact opposite: int interpretes an `unsigned` as `int`. There is no conversation, but undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Ashi: The code does the opposite of what the text asks for.

Comment: bytes... 32 bits... store the same information. There is just an algorithm that take those 4 bytes and says... well how do I have treat them? unsigned? than this is a huge number, signed, than this is a negative number, float than this is... don't know what, but another number

Answer (score 0):

The initial conversion occurs when `-5` is assigned to an `unsigned int`. At that point you have, as suggested, a very large number (the actual value depending on the number of bits in `int` on your machine).

The second "conversion" is really an interpretation. `printf` is asked to take a set of bits and print them out as though they represent an unsigned integer value. This is why the output is `-5`

Comment: The first is implementation defined, the second invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not quite sure why you say that it is undefined. Bits are bits and they represent something tangible. So long as you know what the bits are (and you do) the result can be expected

Comment: Read the standard! It is UB.

Comment: If the format specifier doesn't match the type of the value, the result is undefined. It *could* reinterpret the bits, or it could blow up. Or do something else.